# Removing outliers for a more "realistic" linear programming formulation

Tags: linear-model, outliers

For the past two school quarters I have been collecting data on my study habits. I would like to use this data to formulate a linear program so that I may optimize my study time. The first quarter I did this, there was a very nice correlation between how much time I spent studying for a class and my resulting GPA. Unfortunately, my second quarter was a bit of a fluke, and I did well in a class that I didn't study much for and poorly in a class I did study for often.

[image]

328 is "Real Analysis II" and 407 is "Linear Optimization" - classes that a priori I would believe to be approximately the same difficulty level.

I have reason to believe the "fluke" resulted from idiosyncrasies of the classes - the format of their tests and grade allocation - though I may be in too partial of a position to make such a judgement.

**My question is this**: Should I ignore my "fluke" quarter so that the model fits my idea of how the world should work (i.e. that there is a strong correlation between study time and resulting GPA), or should I look to other metrics? If I find that my GPA most highly correlates with something such as cramming the week before a test or consistently dropping into office hours to glean homework answers from the TA might I be sacrificing my long-term understanding of a subject so that I can "game the system" and maximize my GPA?

Is this something I even want to optimize?

Answer (score 1):

The question in dealing with outliers is whether or not they are generated by the same process as all the other points or not.  If you have reason to believe it is truly a fluke (and since this is your data, you are in the best place to make that decision), the point can be eliminated.  However, you might keep it in based on the idea that there could be other flukes in the future, and you want a model that will best represent reality - now and later.

If you want to deal with these points systematically, at least two alternatives come to mind. The first is to calculate each point's leverage, then establish a threshold to eliminate those points.  The second is to use some type of robust regression (e.g., 'M' or 'MM' estimation) that is less sensitive to outliers.

Comment: Good ideas. Perhaps I am trying to optimize the wrong variable. I would like to learn as efficiently as possible. The assumption is that GPA strongly correlates with learning, and GPA is a much easier metric to estimate than how "much" I learned. This might just be an ill-formed question on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You really must not remove data "so that the model fits my idea of how the world should work." That's wrong on many levels, and will particularly lead you astray if the world doesn't work the way you think it should. (Hint: it probably doesn't, particularly if you are of the age of a typical full-time student.)

It seems that a useful model for GPA should include cramming behavior, office-hour visits, "idiosyncrasies" of the courses including their intrinsic "difficulties," maybe even the season (both your "outliers" were in the summer, apparently). In that case you don't expect a simple plot of GPA versus hours to be necessarily informative, if other variables came into play that themselves affect GPA or that alter the influence of hours studied on GPA.

The practical problem you face is that unless you become a perpetual student you will not have enough data points on yourself to build and test a reliable model before you are done with school. So I'd suggest focusing on optimizing your learning rather than optimizing your model.

Comment: Yes. I'm definitely skeptical of ignoring my most recent data points, especially since I have so little data to work with.